# Redirect print to string list?

Tags: python

I know how to redirect print to a file.

```
import sys

orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = file('out.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f

for i in range(2):
    print ('i = ', i)

sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()
```

I need to do the same but w/out a file: keep print output in a string list. How to do it in Py3k?

Edit: I can have 3rd party prints in a middle part, not my own prints, so code must be universal for usual "print()".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
import sys
class ListStream:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
    def write(self, s):
        self.data.append(s)

sys.stdout = x = ListStream()

for i in range(2):
    print ('i = ', i)

sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
print(x.data)
```

yields

```
['i = ', ' ', '0', '\n', 'i = ', ' ', '1', '\n']
```

---

Tip: You don't need to save the original `sys.stdout`

```
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
```

since `sys.stdout` can be reset with

```
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

---

You could also add some syntactic sugar by making `ListStream` a contextmanager:

```
import sys
class ListStream:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
    def write(self, s):
        self.data.append(s)
    def __enter__(self):
        sys.stdout = self
        return self
    def __exit__(self, ext_type, exc_value, traceback):
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

By adding the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, you can now use `ListStream` in a `with-statement` which will *automatically* reset `sys.stdout` for you when Python exits the `with-suite`:

```
with ListStream() as x:
    for i in range(2):
        print ('i = ', i)

print(x.data)
```

Comment: I thing that is the exact answer for exact question. Plus  1 from me, stdout does not need a copy, stay in sys.__stdout__

Comment: nice idea for the context management, I'm gonna do it that way next time I build a ncurses app ;-)

Comment: Holy crap are context managers really THAT EASY to build? I feel like I've been doing things wrong for so very long....

Comment: It seems that sys.stdout does not point to sys.__stdout__ when in Jupyter notebook, so better to save the original.

Comment: I'm using Spyder (Python 3), and the command

 sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__  

didn't set it back to the default behavior.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of rolling your own class, I think it's easiest to replace `sys.stdout` (which is simply a `TextIOWrapper`) with a `StringIO` instance you keep a reference to:

```
import sys
from io import StringIO

s = StringIO()

sys.stdout = s

print('yo')

print('this is stuff')

print('hi')

s.getvalue()
Out[38]: 'yo\nthis is stuff\nhi\n'

s.getvalue().splitlines()
Out[39]: ['yo', 'this is stuff', 'hi']
```

As @unutbu says, you can restore the original stdout with `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__`; I particlarly like the idea of using a context manager to temporarily redirect stdout to where you want it to go.

Comment: I can have 3rd party prints in a middle part, so code must be universal for usual "print()".

Comment: Gotcha.  I still think using `StringIO` is easier than rolling your own class, editing.

Comment: Love this solution!  Thank you @roippi!

Answer (score 2):

That's something I often do when I need to build a `ncurses` application:

```
import sys

# in this wrapper class you can use a string list instead of a full string like I'm doing
class StdOutWrapper:
    lines = []
    def write(self,txt):
        self.lines.append(txt)

    # here is a method so you can get stuff out of your wrapper class
    # I am rebuilding the text, but you can do whatever you want!
    def get_text(self,beg,end):
        return '\n'.join(self.lines)

mystdout = StdOutWrapper()
sys.stdout = mystdout
sys.stderr = mystdout

# do your stuff here that needs to be printed out in a string list
for i in range(2):
    print ('i = ', i)

# you don't need to make your variable to cache the `stdout`/`stderr` as they still exist
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
```

it is working fine with python 3 and python 2.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function to do it for you, rather than trying to redirect `stdout` to a list (which I don't think could possibly work anyway, but don't quote me on that).

```
def lprint(text):
    global string_list
    try: string_list.append(text)
    except NameError as e:
        string_list = [text]

for i in range(2):
    lprint ("i = {}".format(i))

print(string_list)
[OUT]: ["i = 0","i = 1"]
```

Comment: your solution is bad because you don't answer the OP's question, you're using a `global` variable and your assertion about `stdout` is wrong.

Comment: And yet I'm implementing exactly what he's looking for, doing so in a way that's readable and doesn't require a messy redirect from `stdout`. Just because OP's intended implementation is wrong, doesn't mean my answer is wrong for not using it! :)

Comment: there are places where you *do* want to redirect `stdout` without modifying code from libraries, mostly because the terminal becomes unavailable. A good example is when using the `ncurses` library, so you can move the `stdout` output inside a `ncurses` widget. That kind of use case is legitimate and thus makes your assertion about the OP's intention being wrong... wrong. And you're using a `global`! :-p